# What is an improper affine space at infinity? Schouten: Tensor Analysis for Physicists

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, tensors, projective-geometry

Edit to add:  This clearly deals with projective geometry.  If I figure it out well enough to post a satisfactory answer, I will do so.  If someone else posts a decent answer before then, I will be happy to give you the [brownie points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_points).

---

This question pertains to [Tensor Analysis for Physicists, Second Edition, By: J. A. Schouten.](https://books.google.com/books?id=WROiC9st58gC&lpg=PP1&dq=Tensor%20Analysis%20for%20Physicists%2C%20Second%20Edition%20Schouten&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false)

My understanding of what has been said leading to the quoted statement is as follows:

A space of all allowable coordinate systems under the affine group of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called an *affine space*, or an $E_{n}$. The space of all allowable coordinate system under the centered affine group of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a *centered $E_{n}$*.

The space of all allowable coordinate systems resulting from centered affine transformations of the solution set of the system of $n-p$ linearly independent equations

$$C_{\nu}^{i}x^{\nu}+C^{i}=0,$$

is called a *flat sub-manifold of  $E_{n}$*, and is an  $E_{p}$. Two $E_{p}$'s are said to be *parallel* if they can be transformed into each other by a translation.  Two parallel $E_{p}$'s are said to have the same $p-\text{direction}.$

After introducing the concept of the intersection of $E_{p}$'s and $E_{q}$'s, Schouten states:

> [W]e consider the points of $E_{p}$ 'at infinity' as an *improper $E_{p-1}$* (or *$E_{p-1}$ at infinity*.  Then two parallel $E_{p-1}$'s intersect in an improper $E_{p-1},$ and from this we see that an improper $E_{p-1}$ may be considered as a $p-\text{direction}.$

That statement makes very little sense to me.  Can this be stated in terms of a traditional Euclidean 2-plane in 3-space, in a way that clarifies Schouten's statement?  Am I to envision translating the plane parallel to itself to "positive infinity"?  Am I to consider the "boundary" of the plane at the infinite extremes of its coordinate axes?

The statement appears following equation 3.9 on page 5.  It is available in the preview.